# Is there a way to send full screen notifications with buttons in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

Can we send full screen push notifications like how google sends notification when an unauthorized person/new mobile tries to login the e-mail in flutter?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: No, I dropped the idea after reviewing some documents